# Terraform VM created and then deleted

Tags: linux, centos, terraform, devops, vsphere

terraform version v0.11.10
provider.vsphere v1.9.0
vsphere 5.5 (vcenter running)

vm template -> centos7, vmtools installed, perl installed, selinux off, firewalld off

im trying to spin up a cloned vm in vsphere using terraform. im new to terraform. im using a centos7 vm to clone off of. what happens is the vm gets cloned and then at the configuration stage, around 20% of the way in, it fails and deletes the cloned VM. i have added debug mode and hoping someone with more experience can point out to me where i might be failing.

main error i see is, which i believe is fairly generic. i can attach the full debug log if requested.

"2018/12/09 10:22:57 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

- vsphere_virtual_machine.vm-one: error sending customization spec: Customization of the guest operating system 'centos64Guest' is not supported in this configuration. Microsoft Vista (TM) and Linux guests with Logical Volume Manager are supported only for recent ESX host and VMware Tools versions. Refer to vCenter documentation for supported configurations.

Answer (score 1):

vmware tools was missing, along with perl.